# what is the name of the plastic piece where handlebar/fork would attach to the main bike frame?

Tags: children, balance

i bought a balance bike for the kid and it arrived with a piece missing, they sent a replacement bike but i figured i’d try looking for the piece, i’ve circled it in this picture but it’s basically the top plastic piece where the fork/handlebar attaches, should be the same as the bottom but the top one is missing. does anyone know what it’s called or if i’d be able to find it anywhere? [image]

Comment: It's a proprietary part, you won't find it for sale. You might find it on a used bike or you might be able to rig something.

Answer (score 4):

This part is probably unique to this balance bike--possibly some other balance bikes too, but it is not used on regular bikes.

On an adult bike, there wouldn't be a perfect match, but this would be something like the "upper headset locknut." This is what the parts of an old-style headset (a closer analog to what you've got) look like:

[image]

Comment: Are the identification of the seal and the crown race at the bottom of the image reversed?  What is currently identified as the Seal looks like the race that the bottom set of bearings would ride on.

Comment: Probably yes. And the top "lock nuts" should be singular.